# Find array that is repeating in other array

Tags: algorithm

Let's suppose that array B is made from array A by concatenating it with itself n times
(example: A=[1,2,3], n=3, B=[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3])
What is an efficient algorithm to find A by given B (we don't know n)?
UPD we search for smallest A (when B=[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2], A = [1,2], not [1,2,1,2])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]` means `n` is 4 and not 2, for example. In other words, you're assuming the smallest such sublist, A. Otherwise, there could be multiple solutions.

1. Enumerate the unique integer divisors of the length of B (including 1). These would be the only valid candidates for `n`.
2. For each divisor, starting with the smallest, consider it as a candidate value for `n`:

   a. Take the first `len(B)/n` elements of B and start checking whether it is a sublist that repeats through B (I'll assume you can figure out an efficient way of doing this. I can add a suggestion if you need it.)

   b. If `n` works (you get to the end of B and everything matched), then you're done, otherwise, try the next divisor

Comment: thanks for an anser! in 2.a only comparasion by index from 0 to n by B[i] and B[i+k*n] comes to mind (where k is from 1 to length(B)/n ), is it right or there is more efficient way?

Comment: and in 2.a you meant "take the first k=len(B)/n elements"? (so i in my answer also from 0 to k)

Comment: @СергейМельников yes, that is the net effect. The coding steps turn out to be very simple. If you have B and a candidate A, you start both at index 0, and compare each element in sequence. You keep advancing each index by 1 comparing the elements and resetting the A index to 0 when it hits its maximum (length of A). As soon as you hit a difference, then you know you need to go to the next candidate A.

Comment: @СергейМельников I did mean take the first `n` elements of B. In my description,  `n` is the number of elements in the candidate sublist B. Your original problem statement defines `n` as the length of the sublist.

Comment: ow sorry, only now understood that [1,2,3]*3 is bad example, I meant n is number of repetitions (and for [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2] A=[1,2], n=4 is correct solution) but it seems if we are starting with smallest divisors, exactly this result will be received

Comment: @СергейМельников oh my, sorry actually that was my mistake. I had the correct definition of `n` initially then, in 2a, I got it mixed up. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could basically find the longest prefix in `B` that is also a suffix. You can derive the table from the steps involved in [`KMP pattern matching`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm.

Note that there could be multiple correct solutions.(say `1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2` could have `A` as `1,2,1,2` or `1,2`.

Once found, you will need to rerun the match against the slices of `B` just to make sure the whole array `B` matches the repeating pattern. This is necessary since there could be edge cases such as `1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2` which has `1,2,1,2` as the longest prefix that is also a suffix but it isn't a continuous repetition of `A`.

If the obtained length doesn't divide the length of `B` evenly, you will need to decrease the length evenly(as in factor wise) each time to see which one matches. (Example case: `1,2,1,2,1,2`).

Comment: thanks for an answer! forgot to mention that we search only smallest sublist as lurker mentioned: can we use KMP in this case?

Comment: @СергейМельников Technically you could but it would involve additional steps. You could also binary search for lengths with the values from the KMP table I presume.